# algorithm for cumulative max

Tags: r, algorithm, performance

I'm looking for efficient and/or elegant ways to compute a cumulative max. I'm interested in the algorithm itself and different approaches to the issue.

```
set.seed(1)
vec <- sample(1000,10,TRUE)
# vec
# [1] 266 373 573 909 202 899 945 661 630  62
```

expected:

```
cummax(vec)
# [1] 266 373 573 909 909 909 945 945 945 945
```

Here are 2 solutions to measure yours against :

```
cummax_1 <- function(x) sapply(seq_along(x),function(i) max(x[1:i]))
cummax_2 <- function(x) {
  l <- length(x)
  y <- numeric(l)
  y[1] <- x[1]
  for(i in 2:l) y[i] <- max(x[i],y[i-1])
  y
}

library(microbenchmark)
set.seed(1)
vec_bm <- sample(1e3,1e4,TRUE)
microbenchmark(
  cummax_1 = cummax_1(vec_bm),
  cummax_2 = cummax_2(vec_bm),
  times = 10)

# Unit: milliseconds
#     expr       min        lq      mean   median       uq       max neval
# cummax_1 337.33007 338.92838 350.93473 341.1705 375.4408 377.56073    10
# cummax_2  13.61659  13.85143  14.30533  14.1797  14.8560  15.18955    10
```

Comment: What's wrong with base `cummax`? It produces a mean benchmark of 35.7254 microseconds on your data.

Comment: I'm interested in the algorithm, the source code of `cummax` is not visible

Comment: https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/main/cum.c#L99

Comment: thanks, from what I understand it's pretty much my second solution in C

Comment: The simplest way to rewrite this in base R is with `Reduce`, e.g. `Reduce(max, vec, accumulate = TRUE)` It's in the same order of magnitude as your `for` solution, though nowhere near as fast as `cummax`'s C implementation.

Comment: try `purrr::accumulate(vec, max)` Don't know about speed but the syntax is neat.

Comment: cool, `accumulate` is a wrapper around `Reduce`, so it's more or less the same as @alistaire's solution

Answer (score 0):

Based on your `cummax_2`, you actually can improve the performance by adding a `if` statement, such that the update with max value occurs only if the previous value is greater than the current one.

```
cummax_3 <- function(x) {
    for (i in 2:length(x)) {
        if (x[i] < x[i - 1L]) {
            x[i] <- x[i - 1L]
        }
    }
    x
}
```

## Benchmarking

Given candidates like below

```
cummax_baser <- cummax
cummax_1 <- function(x) sapply(seq_along(x), function(i) max(x[1:i]))
cummax_2 <- function(x) {
    l <- length(x)
    y <- numeric(l)
    y[1] <- x[1]
    for (i in 2:l) y[i] <- max(x[i], y[i - 1])
    y
}

cummax_3 <- function(x) {
    for (i in 2:length(x)) {
        if (x[i] < x[i - 1L]) {
            x[i] <- x[i - 1L]
        }
    }
    x
}
cummax_4 <- function(x) {
    Reduce(max, x, accumulate = TRUE)
}

cummax_5 <- function(x) {
    purrr::accumulate(x, max)
}
```

and the benchmarking

```
set.seed(1)
vec_bm <- sample(1e4)
bm <- microbenchmark(
    cummax_baser = cummax_baser(vec_bm),
    cummax_1 = cummax_1(vec_bm),
    cummax_2 = cummax_2(vec_bm),
    cummax_3 = cummax_3(vec_bm),
    cummax_4 = cummax_4(vec_bm),
    cummax_5 = cummax_5(vec_bm),
    times = 10,
    check = "equivalent",
    unit = "relative"
)
```

we will see the `for`-based `cummax_3` is only second to the fastest built-in `cummax`

```
> bm
Unit: relative
         expr         min          lq        mean      median          uq
 cummax_baser     1.00000     1.00000     1.00000     1.00000     1.00000
     cummax_1 19926.45312 14519.51724 13002.13188 13929.26591 11669.72401
     cummax_2   188.34375   123.17734   125.19633   126.80000   104.20789
     cummax_3    60.10938    39.31527    37.96073    36.83182    32.69176
     cummax_4   442.45312   286.77340   276.61844   280.35682   237.10036
     cummax_5  1365.53125   906.05419   833.08237   881.86818   716.39427
         max neval
     1.00000    10
 10211.17867    10
   145.12104    10
    41.19885    10
   275.93948    10
   653.68876    10
```